# How to set custom labels on y axis

Tags: javascript, svg, google-visualization

I'm using the Google Chart API (not Google Image Chart) to create a line chart with dates on the x axis (bottom) and numbers on the y axis (left). I want to add an r axis (right) with string labels.

If I understand the following page correctly, it's only possible to
have strings on the major axis (x axis for line chart). The minor axes (y and r axes) only
accepts continuous values (like numbers) and not discrete values (like
strings).

[Customizing Axes](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes.html#Terminology)

In Google Image Charts it is possible to work around this by assigning the string data to a value (say from 0 to 100) and assign custom string labels to the axis using the chxl parameter. This is especially easy if the data is evenly spaced.

I've looked at the API reference but can't find anything similar when using the Google Chart API.

Does anyone know if it's possible?

Best regards,
JP

Answer (score 8):

The simplest approach of all is to add the following to your graph options:

```
vAxis: { ticks: [{ v: 0, f: 'Zero'}, {v: 1, f: 'One'}, {v: 2, f: 'Two'}]}
```

In this example, I'm indicating that "Zero" should be displayed instead of 0, "One" instead of 1, etc.

Comment: This works great. Is there a way to customize font size of the ticks on vAxis when I use this code? because the default option doesn't work anymore. `vAxis: { textStyle: { fontSize: 10 }}`

Comment: thanks, i found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393972/how-to-give-style-to-x-axis-of-google-charts

Answer (score 3):

One HACK way to accomplish this goal.

As you know Google Chart uses SVG to draw charts. So, after you drawing your chart, SVG elements inserted to HTML DOM. So, by using jQuery, you can find out vAxis label element and change it's text.

For example, in my case, my vAxis have values as like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]. I want to change it to ["IDLE", "PCH", "FACH", "DCH", ""] instead of number.

I founded out SVG element for vAxis label's DOM structure by using web element inspector tool of my browser.

So, I added code looks like the below after drawing chart.

```
$('#busy_rrclogs svg text[text-anchor="end"]:contains("0")').text("IDLE");
$('#busy_rrclogs svg text[text-anchor="end"]:contains("1")').text("PCH");
$('#busy_rrclogs svg text[text-anchor="end"]:contains("2")').text("FACH");
$('#busy_rrclogs svg text[text-anchor="end"]:contains("3")').text("DCH");
$('#busy_rrclogs svg text[text-anchor="end"]:contains("4")').text("");
```

I added my graph to the below HTML div element as you can see from the above jQuery selector.

```
<div id="busy_rrclogs">
</div>
```

It can resolve my issues even though it's kind of hack.

Answer (score 2):

This hack works as long as google won't change the api in future. Also it works until you don't use experimental option "explorer". If you use zooming then chart is re-rendered on every mousewheel event and your values are gone. Very sad thing is that the chart api does not expose any zoom or re-render events. There is only "ready" event which is fired just once after the chart is drawn. Also, i noticed that I cannot count with the yAxis values being rendered as I provided them to api. If api decides that these strings are too long, it renders only substring of it with tooltip.

So, there is only one clumsy and one real workaround i was able to come up with. I left the clumsy one because it is in line with previous posts

```
var chartDiv = document.getElementById ("chart");
chartDiv .addEventListener ("mousewheel", ProcessChart, false);
//take care of "mousewheel" event browser compatibility!!!

function ProcessChart() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#chart svg text[text-anchor='end']:contains('$C$')").each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);
            var val = parseInt($this.text());
            var label = GetCommunicationLabel(val);

            $this.text(label);                         
        });
    }, 20);
 }
```

Notice that i used setTimeout function to process the labels. The chart is rendered on mousewheel event too and whithout delay you would try to process labels that do not exists yet. 20 milliseconds is just experimental value and it depends on how long your chart is being re-rendered on mousewheel event. Unfortunately the user is able to detect blink when the old values are being replaced with.

I finally found the real solution.

```
vAxes: {
0: {
 format: '#%',
 ticks: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
 //minValue: 0,
 //maxValue: 1,
 //title: batteryText,
},
1: {
 ticks: [ { v: 0, f: GetCommunicationLabel(0) },
          { v: 1, f: GetCommunicationLabel(1) },
      { v: 2, f: GetCommunicationLabel(2) },
      { v: 3, f: GetCommunicationLabel(3) },
      { v: 4, f: GetCommunicationLabel(4) }],
     // format: "#",                    
 textPosition: 'out'
 //minValue: 0,
 //maxValue: 3,
 //title: communicationText,
}
},
```