# How to give style to x-axis of google charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am implementing google charts and I want to give style to x-axis data. I found there the following code to do this.

```
hAxis:{
        title: 'Month',
        textStyle :{
                    fontSize : 10
        }
}
```

I want to underline the text data and change cursor style to the pointer. I searched on the google chart website but didn't get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can modify the `text` elements directly,
when the `'ready'` event fires on the `chart`

you can select which axis labels to modify by using the `'text-anchor'` attribute

x-axis labels have a value of `'middle'`, y-axis `'end'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows([
       ['Category A', 200],
       ['Category B', 110],
       ['Category D', 310],
       ['Category E', 280],
       ['Category F', 175]
    ]);
    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        textStyle: {
          fontSize : 10
        },
        title: 'Month'
      },
      height: 400,
      width: 600
    };

    var chartContainer = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(chartContainer);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      // modify x-axis labels
      var labels = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('text');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
        if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
          label.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
          label.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        }
      });
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: changed above to combo chart, it still works. you can use developer tools of browser to explore elements and find unique identifier. if you could share a working example of the chart, might be able to help...